# Is there a way to turn off flat UI in MacOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, settings, ui

I recently "upgraded" to macOS Sierra (10.12).  I understand that many people have opinions on efficient and aesthetic UIs, but I personally hate (and that is the correct word) a flat UI.  If you like it, great... but is there a way for those of us who don't like it turn it off?

I'm guessing the answer is no - and I've gone through every preference and option I can think might have any bearing.  My Google search didn't turn up anything, either... but there's always a chance that I'm missing something.

If it helps an answer, feel free to get technical: I've been using Apple since the mid-80s, and computers before that; I've been working as a Software Engineer for decades (I'd prefer not to admit how long), and the command line doesn't bother me.  (Yes, yes, I understand that I've asked for a non-flat UI and use the command line.  It's not really hypocrisy... technically.)

**Tl; DR** Is there an option/method to turn off the flat UI in MacOS Sierra (10.12)?

Comment: Short Answer - I don't think you can turn off the flat UI.

Comment: Install Gentoo.

Comment: Which version of Mac OS X did you have before? TheUI has been flat since Yosemite.

Comment: @lhf  I "may" have skipped a few versions...  At work, so I can't verify, but pretty sure I was the one right before Yosemite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't revert back to the UI of previous versions of OS X with Apple's tools.

You can, however, make the UI elements stand out more.

---

### macOS Sierra: Increase the UI's contrast

1. Open System Preferences > Accessibility > Display
2. Tick the checkbox "Increase contrast"

[image: Increase Contrast image]

Description

> Increase contrast
>
> Increase the contrast of items on the screen (such as borders around
>   buttons or boxes) without changing the contrast of the screen itself.

Source: [Apple.com](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25807?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: I'm at work at the moment, but I'll check tonight: this definitely sounds like it should fix (or at least help) my complaint.  If so, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.  Fingers crossed...

Comment: It's still a flat UI... but it's got contrast, and that's lightyears better than it was.  Thanks!